# Select from string till next char is English char

Tags: php, string

I have a simple question, I'm newbie in PHP.

I have this sample string in PHP:

```
this is a test sample thing 
text @INEEDTOCHANGEHERE blah blah blah 
this is a test sample thing 
text @INEEDTOCHANGEHERE blah blah blah 
this is a test sample thing 
text @INEEDTOCHANGEHERE blah blah blah 
...
```

I need to change all the "**INEEDTOCHANGEHERE**" from the string.

It's not depended to the space char that comes after this.

So, I have to find "@" then every English char (a-z) must selected.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Use `preg_replace()`.

Comment: @Barmar Please can u give me the rule?

Comment: Use `'/@\w+/'` as a pattern with preg_replace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks alot

Comment: @Jolie: Do you need more clarifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a simple `'/@\w+/'` regex with `preg_replace`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/@\w+/', 'MY_NEW_VALUE', $input);
```

The `@` matches `a literal`@`, and`\w+` matches 1 or more letters, digits or underscores.